# Binding Tuples to a GridView

Tags: asp.net

```
private List<Tuple<int, string>> GetEmpDetails()
{
    return (from r in dataContext.Emp
    select new Tuple<int, string>(r.ID, r.Name)).ToList();
}
```

I am returing a list of Tuple from WCF Service & Binding to a gridview
But when i bind it to a GridView It shows header as Item1 & Item2. Is there any way I can change the Tuple Property Names

Answer (score 2):

you can't it's a tuple, this is the meaning of tuple, some values attached.
And it wasn't created for this abuse you're doing with it, you shouldn't bind a tuple to ui.

create a presentation model and bind him.